# "base" expansions vs. continued fractions (Are any the same?)

Tags: continued-fractions, number-systems

Does anyone know of any examples of irrational numbers for which their continued fractions "equal" their expansion in some base-number system? More concretely, does there exists some $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, and some $p\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, for which
$$
x=[a_0;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots] = \frac{a_0}{p^0}+\frac{a_1}{p^1}+\frac{a_2}{p^2}+\frac{a_3}{p^3}+\cdots,
$$
where $[a_0;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots]$ means
$$
a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{a_3+\ddots}}}
$$

Comment: Do you want the CF expansion to be 'proper', i.e., $a_i\gt 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: [Trott constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrottConstant.html)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you. That is interesting.